# Python Copy Data From Source Files and Paste In The Most Recent Destination File in Subfolders

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to copy data from .xlsx source files and paste in the most recent corresponding .xlsm destination files in sub folders.

The source files are all in one folder 'c:/users/me/afolder/sourcefolder/' with naming convention ABC_Report.xlsx, DEF_Report.xlsx etc

The destination files are in sub folders and each subfolder has multiple versions of same file so 'c:/users/me/somefolder/destination/ABC/' has files with naming convention ABC 2023 r1.xlsm,  ABC 2023 r2.xlsm, ABC 2023 r3.xlsm, in this case I would like to paste into the most recent file which is r3.xlsm

For subfolder  'c:/users/me/somefolder/destination/DEF/'  the files are DEF 2023 r7.xlsm, DEF 2023 r8.xlsm,  DEF 2023 r9.xlsm, 2023 r10.xlsm in this case I would like to paste into most recent file which is r10.xlsm.

I don't necessarily want to go by filename as there maybe some other random oddly named files in the sub folders so I am going by most recently modified. See my code below: It doesn't work, it throws multiple errors,
sometimes it says name 'latest_file' is not defined,
when I tweak it from list(path) to glob.glob it throws error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C'.
I have tried different tweaks with no luck, any idea what I am doing wrong? or how to make it work?

````
from glob import glob
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def copy_data(src_file: str, dst_file: str) -> None:
# open files
  ws_src = load_workbook(src_file)["src sheet"]
  wb_dst = load_workbook(dst_file, keep_vba=True)
  ws_dst = wb_dst["dest sheet"]

  # configuration
  start_row_src = 2       
  start_row_dst = 10      
  rows2copy = 100000

  # copy data from src_file to dst_file
   input_offset = start_row_dst - start_row_src
   for i in range(start_row_src, rows2copy):
      ws_dst[f"A{i}"].value = ws_src[f"A{i + input_offset}"].value
      ws_dst[f"B{i}"].value = ws_src[f"B{i + input_offset}"].value

    # save the modifications
    wb_dst.save(dst_file)

   #This bottom part of my code that doesn't work the top part works just fine
   # Source filepath
   src_dir_path = = "C:/users/me/afolder/sourcefolder/"

# iterate over all excel files found in source path
workbooks = list(Path(src_dir_path).glob("*.xlsx")) 
for src in workbooks:
        dst_dir_path = "C:/Users/me/somefolder/destinationfolder/{f}/".format(f=(src.stem.replace("_Report", "")))
        #Iterate over files in destination folder to get most recent file
        list_of_files = list(Path(dst_dir_path).glob("*.xlsm"))
for files in list_of_files:
    latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)
lfile = os.path.basename(latest_file[3:15])
dst = dst_dir_path + os.path.basename(src).replace("_Report.xlsx", lfile )
copy_data(src, dst)```
````

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code snippet.  Also, I don't think this code will work as posted since you define the variable```dst_dir_path``` within the scope of a for loop and try to reference the variable outside the loop.

Comment: @itprorh66 indentation fixed, its good in my notebook just gets wonky when I paste it here. Makes sense @ trying to reference the variable outside the loop, I figured I was prolly breaking some python rule doing that but don't know how else to to do it, I have tried many tweaks and untweaks with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposition based on your code:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def most_recent(a_dir, a_cat):
    lst_of_paths = list(Path(a_dir).glob(f"{a_cat}/*.xlsm"))
    return max(lst_of_paths, key=os.path.getctime)

src_dir= r"C:\Users\ohmandy\Desktop\sourcefolder" # where the .xslx are stored
dst_dir= r"C:\Users\ohmandy\Desktop\destination" # where the subfolders and the .xslm are stored

for file in Path(src_dir).glob("*.xlsx"):
    # get the category of the source (ABC, DEF,..)
    category_src= file.stem.split("_")[0]
    
    # load source workbook/worksheet
    wb_src = load_workbook(file)
    ws_src = wb_src["Sheet1"]

    # load destination workbook/worksheet
    wb_dst = load_workbook(most_recent(dst_dir, category_src), keep_vba=True)
    ws_dst = wb_dst["Sheet1"]
    
    # configuration
    start_row_src = 2       
    start_row_dst = 10      
    rows2copy = 10

    # copy data from src_file to dst_file
    # input_offset = start_row_dst - start_row_src
    for i in range(start_row_src, rows2copy+1):
        ws_dst[f"A{i}"].value = ws_src[f"A{i}"].value
        ws_dst[f"B{i}"].value = ws_src[f"B{i}"].value

    # save the modifications
    wb_dst.save(most_recent(dst_dir, category_src))
```

The code basically copy the range `"A2:B11"` (of the `Sheet1`) from an `.xlsx` file and paste it in the most recent corresponding `.xlsm` file (for example starting with *ABC_Report.xlsx|ABC 2023 r3.xlsm* then *DEF_Report.xlsx|DEF 2023 r10.xlsm* and so on..). Feel free to reactivate the offset part.

Comment: Thank you @abokey, I have been struggling with this project and getting the code to work for three weeks now you have gotten me closer than I have ever gotten. When i run the code I get error: TypeError: most_recent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a_cat', it's coming from the code  ```#save modifications
    wb_dst.save(most_recent(dst_dir))``` so I changed it to    ```wb_dst.save(most_recent(src_dir, dst_dir))``` it gives error
NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported
Coming from the code ```lst_of_paths = list(Path(a_dir).glob(f"{a_cat}/*.xlsm"))```

Comment: You're welcome, you can use `wb_dst.save(most_recent(dst_dir, category_src))`. I updated my answer.

Comment: It works like a charm @abokey, Thank You raised to power infinity, You just brought my 3weeks ordeal to a glorious end lol, starring at my screen all day&night, trying bad code after bad code, sleeplessness, skipping meals, neglecting other projects. Programmers and Analysts should not use the M word but what you did here: ```wb_dst = load_workbook(most_recent(dst_dir, category_src), keep_vba=True)``` looks like magic lol didn’t think or know we could do that!

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful @ohmandy ;). I also learned new tricks thanks to your question. We just have to practise and practise a lot. I personnally don't hesitate to ask questions here on SO because there is some amazing and very smart people around here that can make programmers/analysts lifes much easier with the answers they give and their ways of thinking.